# Excel VBA generated header not the same on different PC/Office

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I got a problem which indeed gives me headache.

I got an Excel macro book, which write out invoice by a click of button, but my colleagues complains that all staffs got different problems about the header section.

It runs fine on my PC, the header looks nice and fit, but not on my colleague's PC, the header goes weird.

This is the nice header generated on my PC.

[Nice generated header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR1NG.jpg)
[The weird one from my colleague's PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGru.jpg)

The section which generate the header is here:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = ""
        .Zoom = 100
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4

        .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
        .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(3.6)
        .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(2.9)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.8)
        .FooterMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.8)

        .CenterHeaderPicture.Filename = "Path to company logo.png"
        .CenterHeader = "&G"

        .LeftHeader = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9   Client : " & clnFullName & "御中"
        .RightHeader = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9Date : " & Format(Date, "d-mmm-yyyy") & "&KFFFFFF__" & Chr(10) & "&K000000Inv no. : " & invNumber & "&KFFFFFF__"

        .CenterFooter = "&""Verdana""&9My company Name" & Chr(10) & _
                "My company address" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&10&P / &N"

        .LeftFooter = vbNullString
        .RightFooter = vbNullString


            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 0

    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

My PC is running Windows 10 1809 with Office 2013, while most of my colleagues are using Office 2010.

I have no clues of why such problem happens, I have tested from Excel 2010 to 2016, with combinations from Windows 7 to Windows 10 1903.

Comment: Remove one `Chr(10)` from  `.LeftHeader` & `.RightHeader` .

Comment: If I remove one Chr(10) then the output becomes weird on my PC and probably on those running Office 2013.

I have set the paper size (xlPaperA4), and header / footer size fixed to points. What is the point of remove one Chr(10)??

Comment: Are fonts and Font Size same in your's and your colleagues system ? Can you tell me what they are if yes, i will do some research.

Comment: Hi Mikku, Yes all my colleagues have those fonts (Verdana and others), thank you.

Comment: Use the below answer. I think it should work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, But I found the Problem

**Problem:** When you are changing the size of the Header to `1.2` using the line `.LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.2)` , the default **Font Size** stays at 11 by Default, maybe Not in your system by in your colleagues system.

Now if you try to insert `Chr(10)` five times with Font size 11, it will go past the space allocated for the headers and will be visible in cells weirdly like it's happening.

---

**Solution:** To change the font size before setting the string in Headers. As the Header fond size that you are using is 9, the total space is able to take the String and 5 time `Chr(10)`.

---

**Change these 2 lines:**

```
    .LeftHeader = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9   Client : " & clnFullName & "御中"
    .RightHeader = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9Date : " & Format(Date, "d-mmm-yyyy") & "&KFFFFFF__" & Chr(10) & "&K000000Inv no. : " & invNumber & "&KFFFFFF__"
```

**To:**

```
    .LeftHeader = "&""Verdana""&9" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9   Client : " & clnFullName & "??"
    .RightHeader = "&""Verdana""&9" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "&""Verdana""&9Date : " & Format(Date, "d-mmm-yyyy") & "&KFFFFFF__" & Chr(10) & "&K000000Inv no. : " & invNumber & "&KFFFFFF__"
```

Both are same, its just that we are setting the Font Size Prior to inserting `Chr(10)`, so that they will be of size 9, instead of the default size which can vary in different systems.